# Qt сигналы и слоты

Tags: c++, qt

Есть класс:

```
class RMS_Button : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RMS_Button(QWidget *p) : QPushButton(p) {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(int)), this, SLOT(click(int)));
    }

signals:
    void clicked(int);
public slots:
    void click(int i) {
    qDebug() << "clicked(int)";
    emit clicked(i);
    }
};
```

(QPushButton += **clicked(int)**).
Программа:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    RMS_Button b(nullptr);
    b.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку, не выводит **clicked(int)**. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: QPushButton += clicked(int) - вот это обозначает: void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit clicked(i);
}?

Comment: Нет это не код, просто хотел сказать, что добавил сигнал к QPushButton

Comment: У QPushButton нет сигнала `clicked(int)`, у него есть `clicked(bool)`. Я бы проверил, что возвращает connect.

Comment: http://www.evileg.ru/baza-znanij/qt/signaly-i-sloty-v-qt5.html. В  этой статье пример. То что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

У `QPushButton` есть сигнал `void clicked(bool);`, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку.

```
class RMS_Button : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RMS_Button(QWidget *p) : QPushButton(p) {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(click(bool)));
    }

//signals:
    //void clicked(bool);
public slots:
    void click(bool i) {
    qDebug() << "clicked(int)";
    //emit clicked(i);
    }
};
```

Ну если нужен `int`, то наверно только так:

```
class RMS_Button : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RMS_Button(QWidget *p) : QPushButton(p) {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(click(bool)));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(my_clicked(int)), this, SLOT(click(int)));
    }

signals:
    void my_clicked(int);
    //void clicked(bool i)

public slots:
    void click(bool) {
    qDebug() << "clicked(int)";
       int i = 10;
      emit my_clicked(i);
    }
    void click(int i) {}
};
```

Comment: абстрактный сигнал? это что то новенькое.

Comment: Да, это я знаю, но мне нужно принять int в слот чтобы не писать по слоту на все случаи жизни

Comment: Интересно почему слоты не могут быть шаблонными?

Comment: Они не могут быть шаблонными из за moc'а. Хотя, можно попробовать улучшить moc.

Comment: Попробуй создать свой слот `connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(my_click(bool)));` который `emit` c параметром `int`

Comment: @KoVadim, абстрактный - это лишнее конечно)))

Comment: Да видимо (хоть я и не уверен) можно передать int слоту принимающему bool. Но в самом слоте он таки bool

Comment: Да и вообще, какие нафиг обходные пути все должно быть прозрачно: 1) наследование; 2) определение метода (слота); 3) определение сигнала; 3) приконтачивание п. 3 к п. 2. Вопрос в чем я ошибся? А не как напарить moc!

Comment: @cipher_web, а int i - что за число?

Comment: @cipher_web, так тебе не по нажатию надо?

Comment: Да естественно по нажатию. Я конекчу сигнал clicked

Comment: Во втором варианте я все равно не могу прокинуть int в слот принимающий bool

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46072/discussion-between-nikolay-and-cipher-web).